# Using int for character types when comparing with EOF

Tags: c

Quoting from Kernighan and Ritchie's 'The C Programming Language' Page 16 -

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
int c;
c = getchar();

while(c!=EOF)
{
    putchar(c);
    c = getchar();
} 

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

> "The type `char` is specifically meant for storing such character
>   data, but any integer type can be used. We used `int` for a subtle but
>   important reason. The problem is distinguishing the end of the input
>   from valid data. The solution is that `getchar` returns a distinctive
>   value when there is no more input, a value that cannot be confused
>   with any real character. This value is called `EOF`, for "end of
>   file". We must declare `c` to be a type big enough to hold any value
>   that `getchar` returns. We can't use `char` since `c` must be big
>   enough to hold `EOF` in addition to any possible `char`. Therefore we
>   use `int`.".

I looked up in stdio.h, it says `#define EOF (-1)`

The book conclusively states that `char` cannot be used whereas this program "works just fine" (See EDIT) with `c` as `char` data type as well. What is going on? Can anyone explain in terms of bits and signed values?

**EDIT:**
As Oli mentioned in the answer, the program cannot distinguish between `EOF` and `255`. So it will not work fine. I want to know what's happening - Are you saying that when we do the comparison c!=EOF, the EOF value gets cast to a char value = 255 (11111111 in binary; i.e. the bits 0 through 7 of EOF when written in 2's complement notation)?

Comment: Define "works just fine". What inputs have you tried?

Comment: @CharlesBailey - I am aware that the program will not work fine with 255 input as Oli mentioned in the answer below. I am trying to explore what is happening here. EDITing the question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program doesn't work fine; it won't be able to distinguish between `EOF` and `255`.

The reason it appears to work correctly is because `char` is probably `signed` on your platform, so it's still capable of representing `-1`.

Comment: True. Are you saying that when we do the comparison c!=EOF, the EOF value gets cast to a char value = 255 (11111111 in binary; i.e. the bits 0 through 7 of EOF when written in 2's complement notation)?

Comment: No, promotions rules are such that in `c!=EOF`, the comparison is made on ints.

Comment: And on a platform where `char` was an unsigned type, the expression `c != EOF` would always be true.

Comment: Turns out that char c = -127 and char c = 129 when used with putchar output the same value (i.e. the value corresponding to the ASCII equivalent of 10000001 since both -127 and 129 have this representation).

Comment: @Vikesh, `putchar` convert its input character to an `unsigned char` and write the result. -127 and 129 are thus indeed converted to the same character in 8 bit char implementations.

Answer (score 8):

`getchar` result is the input character converted to `unsigned char` and then to `int` or `EOF` i.e. it will be in the -1 — 255 range that's 257 different values, you can't put that in an 8 bit `char` without merging two of them. Practically either you'll mistake `EOF` as a valid character (that will happen if `char` is unsigned) or will mistake another character as `EOF` (that will happen if `char` is signed).

Note: I'm assuming an 8 bit `char` type, I know this assumption isn't backed up by the standard, it is just by far the most common implementation choice.

Comment: Cool. So, one way we can avoid this ambiguity is that we use an int where all characters are represented by bits 0 through 7 (# 255) and EOF can be represented as 1111....32 times..... (assuming a 4 byte int)? There will be no conflict here.

Comment: That's indeed the result of `getchar()`.