# getch and putchar not working without return

Tags: c, ncurses, getch, putchar

I have been trying to get `getch` to work in another program with no success. So I have made the most basic program I can using `getch` the way I want it to work in the main program.

I have researched the need for `noecho`, `cbreak`, `initscr` and `nodelay`, I have also tried using `newscr()` but to no success.

The problem I am having is that the chars aren't being printed to the screen till I hit "enter", when they should be `put` to the screen every loop. Why is this happening? Also the cursor doesn't return to the left of the screen at the new line. eg.

```
abc  
   def
      ghi
```

I have looked for the answer but am stumped again...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
  {
     initscr();cbreak(); noecho();nodelay(stdscr,0);
    char c ;
    while((c=getch())!=EOF){
    putchar(c);}

    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: If your wondering why I'm doing this, I am trying to get input from stdin and only print to stdout lines that aren't empty.

Comment: If you just want to implement a text filter, it's a very bad idea to bring in terminal control via curses. Interactive character-at-a-time input has nothing to do with the problem of filtering out empty lines.

Comment: To copy nonempty lines from stdin to stdout, try `grep '.'`. I can assure you that it doesn't use ncurses.

Comment: @Kaz; I have used character-at-a-time filtering sucessfully with a redirected stdin file but when using it just with stdin the terminal echos the stdin which i don't want.  So Hence why I'm Trying terminal control

Comment: All standard text processing tools will echo the input. This is a useful and good thing. `sed`, `awk`, `grep`, you name it.  The echoing is not affecting the operation; it is just local feedback in the operating system's TTY driver that enables you to see what the heck you are typing.

Comment: @Kaz; Which I don't want in this case. Thanks anyway tho.

Comment: By the by, you should read `getch()` into an `int`, not a `char`.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464030/using-int-for-character-types-when-comparing-with-eof

Comment: +1 for saying it is homework. I cannot comment further from paulsm4
. Look up cursers.

Comment: @Ed Heal; well its gone well beyond the required homework but I hate it when something won't work the way I want it to so I'm spending heaps of extra time on something I probably won't even submit..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not seeing the output because your `stdout` stream is line buffered.

Your program is getting the individual characters all right; but the output stream is buffering them.

Try `fflush(stdout);` or switching `stdout` to unbuffered mode with `setbuf(stdout, NULL);`.

The problem with disabling buffering is that it's inefficient for bulk data processing when the output isn't a terminal.

You can make it conditional on the standard output being a tty:

```
if (isatty(fileno(stdout)))  /* #include <unistd.h> */
  setbuf(stdout, NULL);
```

To return the cursor to the start of the line, you need to put out a carriage return `\r`. This is because curses' `cbreak` mode has disabled the `ONLCR` tty mode (on Output, when sending NL add CR).

If you unconditionally add `\r`, then it will appear in files when your output is redirected. So again you need some `isatty` hack.

A much better might be to learn how to use the `tcgetattr` and `tcsetattr` functions to precisely control specific tty parameters, if all you want is to do character-at-a-time input without echo, and not actually develop an interactive curses-based program.

Do you really want character-at-a-time input, or just to diable echo? It's easy to disable echo. Call `tcgetattr` to fill a `struct termios` with the current settings of file descriptor 0 (if it is a tty). Flip some flags to turn off echoing, then call `tcsetattr` to install the updated structure.  When your program exits, be nice and put back the original one. Done.

Comment: But it won't solve that lack of carriage return. I updated the answer with more.

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at them, it will probably be a lot less sloppy than the way I'm doing it. p.s. `if((c == '\n'))putchar('\r');}` works but very crap code I know.

Comment: ;Thanks got it going with `tcsetattr` like a dream after many googlies as to how to set the flags Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, ncurses is a good way to get character-by-character control.

And yes, you must call "initscr()" and "cbreak()".

SUGGESTIONS:

1) Compare your code with this ncurses "hello world":

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{   
    initscr();          /* Start curses mode          */
    printw("Hello World !!!");  /* Print Hello World          */
    refresh();          /* Print it on to the real screen */
    getch();            /* Wait for user input */
    endwin();           /* End curses mode        */

    return 0;
}
```

2) See what happens if you do a "refresh()" and/or remove the "noecho()".

3) This tutorial has lots of good info that might also help:

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/

Comment: Thanks Bookmarked, and clearly I didn't understand what a window was.

Comment: Hi - Kaz is right.  If you want terminal control for a text-mode application, Ncurses is a good choice.  If you want a simple filter to strip empty lines (as you explained subsequently), just use "sed" or "grep".  For example: "`cat myfile|grep '.'`

Comment: I Would use cat... but this is for homework hence the making of a filter.