# C: ncurses, initscr() changes behaviour of getchar()?

Tags: c, ncurses, curses, getchar, getch

I am just playing around with ncurses and so, and I discovered a really weird behaviour.

When i use initscr() from the ncurses lib, and afterwards i use a normal getchar(), then the program terminates after pressing the first key.

The normal getchar() behaviour I would expect, is that i can type (more or less) as long till I press return.

```
#include "curses.h"

int main()
{
    initscr();
    getchar();
  //endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone explain me why this happens?

Comment: Record and display the value from `getchar()` before exiting.  Include `endwin()` unless you like resetting your terminal characteristics (or, I suppose, unless you're using an IDE which creates a new terminal window when it runs a program).  When you use `initscr()` or similar, you change the rules for standard input. Don't expect the normal behaviour; the rules have changed.

Comment: You can find a good example and more for your situation in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256477/getch-and-putchar-not-working-without-return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256477/getch-and-putchar-not-working-without-return).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

curses initializes the terminal input to **raw** mode (which in turn makes the connected stream act as if it is *unbuffered*), so that curses can detect single-character input.  `getchar` assumes that the input is buffered, so that you would press <kbd>*Enter*</kbd> to end an input line.  In **raw** mode, `getchar` returns right away, because a `read` call will find something as soon as you press a key.

Besides `endwin`, you could use other curses functions for switching back/forth between the terminal's raw/cooked modes (see the manual for [**`reset_shell_mode`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_kernel.3x.html#h3-reset_prog_mode_-reset_shell_mode) and [**`reset_prog_mode`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_kernel.3x.html#h3-reset_prog_mode_-reset_shell_mode)).

Comment: This is not correct. Stdio buffering has nothing to do with it. Rather it's about cooked/canonical mode on the tty. Moreover getchar does not "assume input is buffered", and is not doing anything wrong after the terminal is set to uncooked mode.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE would you mind elaborating in your very own answer? Or at the least in another comment, because what you write may be factual, but doesn't help the OP as it isn't constructive, thank you.