# print and count strings from <tab.txt in C

Tags: c, string, printing, count

could somebody help me with this? I'm beginner in C programming and I don't know how I can print the strings from table from stdin and how can I count how many strings are there...

for example './program select row 3 < tab.txt but I have no idea how to do it...

```
int i;

char c(stidn);
int i, *p_i;
p_i = &i;

int select() {
while ((c=getchar()) != EOF)
  {
  i++;
  }
}

int row(){
if (i == (argc 4))
printf("%s\n", p_i);
}
```

then I will call select and then row in main()

```
if ((argc == 4) && (strcmp("select", argv[1]) == 0)){
  if (argc 4 == p_i)
  {
  row;
  }
```

I know this is wrong but as I sad...I have no idea what I can do :|

Comment: come up with something and we will help. Atleast give it a try, paste your code and problem and we will try to help.

Comment: Did you try anything? Show us your code!

Comment: How is your table formatted. e.a. every string on a new line, every string seperated by ;,...

Comment: Its getchar() not getcahr().

Comment: It's classic table in text editor, where are some words and numbers on the line separated by "white-space" and the next line is created by Enter

Answer (score 0):

First we need to get the right row. We will do this be counting all the newlines we detect when reading the input.

```
unsigned int GoToRow(unsigned int row) //First row has index zero
{
    unsigned int nlCount = 0;
    int c = 0;

    while(nlCount < row  && c != EOF)
    {
        c = getchar();

        if(c == '\n')
        {
            nlCount++;
        }
    }
    return nlCount;
 }
```

The next thing we need to do, is to get the row from the input.

```
void GetRow(char* pString, int maxchars)
{
    int charCount = 0;

    while((charCount + 1 < maxchars) || pString[charCount - 1] == '\n')
    {
        pString[charCount] = getchar();
        charCount++;
    }
    pString[charCount] = '\0';
}
```

The main function of our program

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    unsigned int rownumber = 3;
    char rowdata[500];

    if(argc == 4 && (strcmp(argv[1], "select") == 0) && (strcmp(argv[2], "row") == 0))
    {
       rownumber = atoi(argv[3]);
    }

    int rowscounted = GoToRow(rownumber);
    GetRow(rowdata, 500);
    rowscounted++;
    rowscounted += GoToRow((unsigned int)-1); //Go to the end of the data
    printf("Number of rows : %d\n Selected row : %s", rowscounted, rowdata);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But I don't need count words in string, but the all strings in table...and select row 'x' is not in define in the main but it is arument when I run program in the console

Comment: Should use `int c = 0;`, not `char`  [Ref](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464030/using-int-for-character-types-when-comparing-with-eof)