# confusion about int, char, and EOF in C

Tags: c, char, int, eof

I'm learning K&R's classic C programming book 2nd edition, here's an example on page 17:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* copy input to output*/
main()
{
    int c; 
    // char c works as well!!
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        putchar(c);
}
```

it's stated in the book that `int c` is used to hold `EOF`, which turns out to be `-1` in my Windows machine with GCC and can't be represented by `char`. However, when I tried `char c` it works with no problem. Curiously I tried some more:

```
int  a = EOF;
char b = EOF;
char e = -1;
printf("%d %d %d %c %c %c \n", a, b, e, a, b, e);
```

and the output is `-1 -1 -1` with no character displayed (actually according to ASCII table for `%c, c` here there should be a `nbs(no-break space)` displayed but it's invisible).

So how can `char` be assigned with `EOF` without any compiler error?

Moreover, given that `EOF` is `-1`, are both `b` and `e` above assigned `FF` in memory? It should not be otherwise how can compiler distinguish `EOF` and `nbs`...?

**Update**:

most likely `EOF 0xFFFFFFFF` is cast to `char 0xFF` but in `(c = getchar()) != EOF` the the LHS `0xFF` is int promoted to `0xFFFFFFFF` before comparison so type of `c` can be either `int` or `char`.

In this case `EOF` happens to be `0xFFFFFFFF` but theoretically `EOF` can be any value that requires more than 8 bits to correctly represent with left most bytes not necessarily being `FFFFFF` so then `char c` approach will fail.

Reference:
K&R The C Programming Language 2e

[image]

Comment: seems to me like -1 fits just fine into a signed 8bit integer (char). can you post the entire statement? because `EOF can't be represented by char` seems wrong to me. also ASCII is only 0-127, nbs is part of *extended ascii*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using int for character types when comparing with EOF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464030/using-int-for-character-types-when-comparing-with-eof)

Comment: You need some way of distinguishing between `0xFF` and `EOF`, otherwise it would be impossible for C to work with binary files that contain bytes with a value of `0xFF`. This is why functions like `getchar()` return integer values.

Comment: The problem will come, when there is `0xFF` file data. Then as `char` you won't distinguish it from `EOF`. `getchar` returns `int` type for a very good reason.

Comment: Again, **main(){}** should be **int main(void){}**

Comment: Did you say "the output of printf("%d %d %d %c %c %c \n", a, b, e, a, b, e); is "-1 -1 -1"?? Edit: Oh, I guess you did -- the -1 chars didn't translate intot anything displayable.

Comment: "according to ASCII table for %c, c here there should be a nbs(no-break space)" is incorrect.  There is no "nbs(no-break space)" in [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).  Likely you are referencing some other table that has some ASCII similarities.  And were is `c`? in your post?

Comment: "most likely EOF 0xFFFFFFFF is cast to char 0xFF but in (c = getchar()) != EOF the the LHS 0xFF is int promoted to 0xFFFFFFFF before comparison so type of c can be either int or char." is quite messed up.  Better to this in terms of values and not bit patterns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`EOF` and `0xFF` are not the same. So compiler has to distinguish between them. If you see the [man page for `getchar()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar), you'd know that it returns the character read as an unsigned char cast to an int or EOF on end of file or error.

Your `while((c = getchar()) != EOF)` is expanded to

```
((unsigned int)c != (unsigned int)EOF)
```

Comment: Thanks! So in `char c = getchar()` is the returned `int` value truncated so only rightmost 8 bits are assigned to `c`?

Comment: EOF is defined as int, it is not 0xff, it is actually 0xFFFFFFFF (-1 as 32bit int) (usually). but if you cast 0xFFFFFFFF to char it will be 0xFF. so yes

Comment: Indirectly. Casting 0xFFFFFFFF to `char` would make it 0xFF.

Comment: Alright so in `char c` and `(c = getchar()) != EOF` here `c` is first assigned with `0xFF` and then extended again to `0xFFFFFFFF` to compare with `EOF` so the whole thing works as `int c` am I right??

Comment: `c` is converted to `int` before comparison thanks to integer promotion rule.

Comment: Hm. I do not think that anything is necessarily cast/converted  to unsigned int. `getchar()` returns a signed int. Thus the assignment `c = getchar()` converts a signed int to a char (which may or may not be signed). The result of the assignment has type and value of the left side, i.e. type char, the value is "unchanged" as far as the bit pattern goes (because we are guaranteed to not have an overflow). Now `(c = getchar()) != EOF` is a comparison between char and int.

Comment: ... The conversions for the comparison now depend on the signedness of char. If char is signed, the left side of the comparison is promoted to signed int, which EOF already is. If char is unsigned I'm afraid both are promoted to unsigned int which makes EOF really big and a char with the value of 0xff 255, so that they would compare unequal, perhaps surprisingly, at least to me. Am I Wrong?

Comment: @Peter: No, you are right about the conversions for comparison. Though I tend to disagree about the first statement wherein you said that nothing is cast/converted to unsigned int. The balancing rules of C  implicitly convert the `int` to `unsigned int`, because each operand must have the same type?

Comment: Both must have the same type, but none has unsigned int in the beginning. Certainly if char is signed there is no unsigned int promotion (why should there be one?). If char is unsigned I'm less certain -- the rules changed and it may be that even then the char will be promoted to int (since int can hold all unsigned char values). In that case too, the comparison would simply be performed between two ints.

Comment: @Peter You are wrong about "If char is unsigned I'm afraid both are promoted to unsigned int ..."  A `char` is promoted to `int` if `CHAR_MAX <= INT_MAX` which is almost _always_ the case.  (Else it is promoted to `unsigned`.)  This answers "is expanded to `((unsigned int)c != (unsigned int)EOF)`" is certainly wrong too.  (I see the improvement in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32720934/confusion-about-int-char-and-eof-in-c#comment53286564_32721076)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, do you mean it should be `signed int` instead of `unsigned int`?  I had the same question as OP but haven't got to data types yet, so I'm not sure. Also, the link in your comment redirects to the comment before yours, did you mean to link to another post?

Comment: @user51462 When `CHAR_MAX <= INT_MAX` (very common), `int c; ... while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)` is sufficient.  Otherwise more  code needed.

Answer (score 2):

This code works because you're using *signed* `char`s. If you look at an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) you'll find two things: first, there are only 127 values. 127 takes seven bits to represent, and the top bit is the sign bit. Secondly, `EOF` is not in this table, so the OS is free to define it as it sees fit.

The assignment from `char` to `int` is allowed by the compiler because you're assigning from a small type to a larger type. `int` is guaranteed to be able to represent any value a `char` can represent.

Note also that `0xFF` is equal to 255 when interpreted as an `unsigned char` and -1 when interpreted as a `signed char`:

```
0b11111111
```

However, when represented as a 32 bit integer, it looks very different:

```
255 : 0b00000000000000000000000011111111
-127: 0b11111111111111111111111110000001
```

Comment: Hr-rmp,  0xFF is equal to 255.

Comment: ok, i wont edit further without comment. 0xFF == 255 and 0xFF is -1 (as 8bit signed) not -127. can you fix that?

Comment: i fixed it completely now :D. seeing that the last 8 bit are equal should really explain the problem

Comment: Your edit defeats the purpose of my answer. I wanted to show that 255 and -127 are not equivalent in 32 bit 2s complement. -1 has no place here.

Comment: @Alex i think the problem is, that one has to understand that `(char)0xFF == -1` and `(int)0xFFFFFFFF == -1` are not equal, but if you cast `(char)0xFFFFFFFF` they are (bitwise). the `==` operator will return true though. but well, your post, your choice

Answer (score 0):

Think values, not bit patterns.

Recall `char` is either *signed* or *unsigned*.  `char` has the same range as `signed char` or `unsigned char`.

---

> it's stated in the book that `int c` is used to hold `EOF`, which turns out to be -1 in my Windows machine with GCC and can't be represented by char.

> So how can `char` be assigned with `EOF` without any compiler error?

"and can't be represented by char" is amiss.  `EOF` is some negative `int` value, very often -1.  When `char` is *signed*, `char b = EOF;` is just fine.  It is like `char b = -1;` and `b` has the value of -1.

When `char` is *unsigned*, then `char b = EOF;` as part of the initialization, simply converts the value of `EOF` to the maximum `char` value and then assigns.  `b` has the value of `CHAR_MAX`, which in this case is the same as `UCHAR_MAX`, often 255.

**Deeper**

`getchar()` returns an `int` in the `unsigned char` range or the negative `EOF`.  This is true if `char` is *signed* or *unsigned*.

To well distinguish the typical 257 different possible return values of `getchar()`, save the result in an `int`.