# How do I get fputc function to work on windows 11?

Tags: c, dev-c++

I'm trying a very simple programm where whatever is written in test.txt gets copied in up.txt but in capital letters. I'm using dev c++ on windows 11 and after running the programm the up.txt file is created but it is empty and i can't figure out why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){
    FILE *fpin, *fpout; 
    char x;
    fpin=fopen("test.txt","r");
    if(fpin==NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"read error\n");
        exit(666);
    }
    fpout=fopen("up.txt","w");
    if(fpout=NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"write error/n");
        exit(667);
    }
    while((x=fgetc(fpin))!=EOF){
        fputc(toupper(x),fpout);
    }
    fclose(fpin);
    fclose(fpout);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I tried the same programm on linux succesfully but i'm not sure why it doesn't work on windows

Comment: Your code is wrong: change `if (fpout = NULL)` to `if (fpout == NULL)`. I don't see how your code can work on any platform.

Comment: use `int x` instead of `char` because `EOF` is outside the range of 256 valid `char` values

Comment: @Bodo that's not the main problem though.

Comment: ```exit(666)``` ---> What?

Comment: You might exchange those `fprintf(stderr,"some error")` with `perror("some error")`, which will print `"some error: <error message>"` in future programs -- so you get an idea *what went wrong*.

Comment: @DevSolar yes, but in this particular code the `fprintf(stderr, ...` is never executed because of the `if(fpout=NULL)`

Comment: @Jabberwocky That's why it's a comment on his coding style, not an answer to his problem. ;-)

Comment: @sartttt As for your question, it will likely be closed as "caused by a typo". Don't let that discourage you: Your question was valid, and actually *very good* as far as first SO questions go. You included a [mcve], which most first-timers don't, and described the problem. The close votes are basically just technical (the answer helped you, but is unlikely to help future readers, so it will not be listed). +1 to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way this code can work on any platform. Are you sure the code you ran on Linux is actually this exact same code you show in the question?

The main problem is here:

```
   fpout=fopen("up.txt","w");
                         // up.txt is now created

   if (fpout = NULL) {   // you're using an assignment here (=) instead 
                         // of the == operator
      fprintf(stderr,"write error/n");
      exit(667);
   }
   // fpout is NULL now
```

`if (fpout = NULL)` is not a comparision, but it simply assigns `NULL` to `fout`. As the result is `false` (which is more or less the same thing as NULL), `fprintf(stderr,"write error/n");exit(667)` will not be executed and the program just continues.

Then in the `while` loop that follows, you're writing into a NULL FILE pointer, which is undefined behaviour, most likely the program will crashes or it might just do nothing or just quit, or maybe something else). Look up "C undefined behaviour" on your favorite search engine.

---

There is another subtle bug: `char x;` should be `int x;` because `fgetc` returns an `int`, not a `char`.

Read following articles for more information:

- [Why does fgetc() return int instead of char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49063518/why-does-fgetc-return-int-instead-of-char)
- [confusion about int, char, and EOF in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32720934/confusion-about-int-char-and-eof-in-c)

Comment: Just wondering: why did it work on Linux? Because it was not quite the same code you posted?

Comment: There's a 2nd more subtle bug too: `(x=fgetc(fpin))!=EOF` Since `x` is  `char` it can never be equal to `EOF`. Feel free to add that to your answer as well, for completeness.

Comment: @Lundin correct, this has been mentioned in one of the comments. But yes, I'll add it to the questio, thnks.