# I'm trying to read text from a .txt file and count the amount of words in it using c

Tags: c, file, char, fgetc

This is what I have so far. The issue is that the "count" variable is not properly adding to itself when it hits a newline or space character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

    char c;
    int count = 0;
    int* ptr;
    int size;

    FILE *file = fopen("file.txt", "r"); //Reads from input file

    //Test to see if the file exists
    if (file == NULL){
        printf("ERROR 1: TARGET INPUT FILE DOES NOT EXIST, HAS BEEN RENAMED OR HAS BEEN MOVED.");
        exit(1);
    }

    c = fgetc(file);
    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF){

        if(c == " " || c == "\n"){
            count++;
        }

    }

    fclose(file);

    printf("Number of words present in given file: %d", count);  
    return 0;
}
```

I don't have much of an idea as to *why* it is failing, although I have looked up multiple sources that have pretty much this exact code that seems to work for them. The output should return a number representing the amount of words in the .txt file.

Comment: 0) You need to change the type of `c` to `int`. 1) **turn on all your compiler warnings**: the comparison between a character (`c`) and a string (`" "` or `"\n"`) is illegal.

Comment: _"...I have looked up multiple sources that have pretty much this exact code..."_ could you show the links to one or two of them?

Comment: Your first stop should always be the compiler warnings: `if(c == " " || c == "\n")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters the variable `c` should be declared as having type `int` instead of `char`.

Also ths call of `fgetc` before the while loop

```
c = fgetc(file);
```

is ignored

You are comparing an integer with pointers

```
if(c == " " || c == "\n"){
```

because string literals in the above expressons are converted to pointers to their first characters. The compiler should issue a message for this if statement.

But if you will write instead

```
if(c == ' ' || c == '\n'){
```

using character constants nevertheless the approach is incorrect because it does not take into account adjacent spaces.

Comment: You should also mention that `char c;` should be `int c;` and maybe point to one of the numerous dupes.

Answer (score 1):

1. `fgetc()` returns an `int`, not a `char`. So `c` should be declared `int`.
2. You read the first character of the file...and discard it. Did you mean to do this? I can see a good reason for doing it this way, I'm just not sure you were thinking the same way.
3. In `if(c == " " || c == "\n")`, you're comparing your single character against strings, because you've double-quoted `" "` and `"\n"`. You can't do this in C - or, at least, the results will be rather random. Use single quotes instead, so `if(c == ' ' || c == '\n')`. That way, you're comparing against single character values.
4. You declared `int* ptr;` and `int size;` but didn't use them. Might as well delete those lines. A decent compiler will warn you about unused variables.
5. Your approach is incorrect, in any case. If your file contained a lot of empty lines, or more than one space between words, your word count would be incorrect. You should be counting the number of times non-whitespace is immediately followed by whitespace (or EOF), and ignoring repeated whitespace. I'll leave that as an exercise for the student!

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF){
    if((c>='A'&& c<='Z') || (c>='a'&& c<='z')){
        while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF){
            if(c == '\n' || c == ' '){
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

in initial code, if I have "fsdfs    \n asfsf  " in file, count may be larger than
it should be.

Comment: This is a poor answer, because: 1: there is no explanation. 2: There is no mention about why `char c;` is wrong. 3: the code is overly complicated.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, what is the problem with using `char c` instead of `int c`? I've heard it, but I don't understand the issue with the conversion. I know that `fgets` returns an `int` casted from `unsigned char`. Is it the possible conversion to `signed char` -- if that's what `char` actually is? That would not be an issue if you're guaranteed ASCII.

Comment: @Surge read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32720934/confusion-about-int-char-and-eof-in-c, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48870708/why-is-type-int-needed-to-handle-eof-and-return-of-getchar and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782080/what-is-eof-in-the-c-programming-language and probably a few others