# printf prints additional * character

Tags: c, loops, getchar

I have a very simple code to convert Upper case to lower case:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
char c;
int i=0;
for (i=0;i<10;i++){
    c=getchar();
    c=c-'A'+'a';
    printf("%c\n",c );
    }
return 0;
}
```

But running this simple code always I have an additional `*` character at output. It prints the char following by a `*`. Take a look:

```
D
d
*
D
d
*
E
e
*
```

Where does this come from?

Comment: Run a debuger, check the value of `c` in each iteration.....

Comment: Fyi, [`getchar()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns `int`, and should be used accordingly.

Comment: What was your input to this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After each *input*, due to <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key pressed, there's a `newline` that is stored in the input buffer and read in the next iteration by `getchar()`.

a `newline` (`\n`) has ASCII value of `10` (decimal), added to the `'a'-'A'` which is 32 (decimal), produces 42 (decimal), which prints the `*`.

FWIW, `getchar()` returns an `int`. It's a very bad idea to store the return value of `getchar()` into a `char` variable, as, in case, `getchar()` fails, one of the possible return values, for example `EOF` will not be fitting into a `char` type, causing issues in further conditional check of even debuggin attempt. Change

```
char c;
```

to

```
int c = 0;
```

Comment: So how to get rid of this problem?

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy Consume the `'\'n` with a dummy `getchar`... or changing the code using `scanf`? many ways

Comment: These things have been answered 1000 times before. For questions about mysterious input phenomenon caused by trailing new line characters in stdin, please refer to wiki [How to read / parse input in C? The FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178520/how-to-read-parse-input-in-c-the-faq) (feel free to improve if something is missing). For questions regarding bugs related to EOF being an int, there's countless duplicates as well.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464030/using-int-for-character-types-when-comparing-with-eof) seems to be a good dupe for "EOF is actually int".