# Using int or char data types and doing exercises from the K&R - "The C programming language" book?

Tags: c

First of all, please excuse me for asking this question because there are already dozens of similar variations of it. However, I am not entirely sure If I can understand it correctly. So, please let me explain what I managed to understand and correct me if I am wrong.

This is an example from the K&R book:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    main()
    {
1)      int c;

2) 4)   while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
3)      putchar(c);
    }
```

So, I understand the above program like this:

*1)* We declare `c` as `int` instead of `char` because using a `char` data type won't always operate correctly and it will eventually mess it up. `Char` data type has variations depending on the system and it could be by default either `signed` [−127, +127] or `unsigned` [0, 255]. Also, `EOF` is not always `-1` by default because it depends on the system and the compiler as well.

- *1.1)* So, if we declare `c` as `char` and it's by default `signed char` on the system then it will still work but it will mess up if we enter a character equal to ASCII 128 and above? **What will happen?** `getchar()` will return a value of maximum possible ASCII value for the selected data type, 127?
- *1.2)* In the opposite, if we declare `c` as `char` and by default is `unsigned char` on the system then `getchar()` will always be **NOT** equal to `EOF` no matter what because we cannot store a negative value, **right?**

Because all of the variations above it's correctly to declare `c` as `int` to avoid a possible conflict?

2) We type some characters as input `c = getchar()` grabs this input and convert it to ASCII number after that it checks to make sure it's not equal to `EOF`.

3) If it is **NOT** equal to `EOF`, it displays the input characters as output.

4) It goes back in a state where we must input new characters to continue the loop.

*Is all above correct?*

*[Additional question]* Also, the statement `getchar() != EOF` will output `1` or `0` as value. `1` value will mean that `getchar()` is **NOT** equal to `EOF`. And `0` as value will shows us that `getchar()` is actually **equal** to `EOF`, right?

*[Additional question]* I saw  another question from another user here on Stack Overflow regarding `getchar()` and `char` data type, however, I cannot understand the answer of [Oliver Charlesworth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129570/oliver-charlesworth).

> Your program doesn't work fine; it won't be able to distinguish
>   between EOF and 255.

What that means? Could you explain it to me? Also, I can't understand what this means too:

> 0 through 7 (# 255) and EOF can be represented as 1111....32
>   times..... (assuming a 4 byte int)? There > will be no conflict here.

[Link to the Oliver Charlesworth's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464030/using-int-for-character-types-when-comparing-with-eof/8464039#8464039)

---

***UPDATE***

Thank you all! Regarding this:

> `0 through 7 (# 255) and EOF can be represented as 1111....32
>   times..... (assuming a 4 byte int)? There > will be no conflict
>   here.`

If I understood it correctly after all the answers and explanations below. That means `EOF` with value `-1` will be represented as `1111 1111` for example and if the data type is `char` then it will think it's #255 because it's only 8 bit and it will be stored in the memory exactly as it is 0xFF (#255) with no other indications (in a few words: data is lost and now instead of value `-1` it means something entirely different), **is that correct?** So, to avoid this confusion, we allocate 4 bytes when we declare the `c` as `int` to make sure no data will be lost and it will store the `EOF` value `-1` in 32 bits like `32 times...1111 1111` including a sign that it's also a negative value. **Do I understand it correctly?**
Thanks once again!

Comment: Is the K&R book still valid?

Comment: Please google `man getchar` to find out why it is `int c` and not `char c`

Comment: *We declare c as int instead of char because using a char data type won't always operate correctly and it will eventually mess it up*... Do check the return type of `getchar()`

Comment: Hence reading the manual page :-)

Comment: It's much simpler than that: You use an int because getchar() returns an int. That int can have all character values *and* one additional value called EOF, which is different from any char. That's it.

Comment: The historical reason for promoting `char` to `int` automatically is that, on the DEC PDP minicomputers C was originally written for, `int` represented the native word size of the machine, and to do anything with a `char`, you would have to load it into an `int`-sized register. So specifying 8-bit math for `char` would have involved a lot of bitmasking. Also the reason for widening `float` to `double`, although that at least is more numerically stable. It’s stuck with us for backward compatibility.

Comment: @EdHeal : Regarding K&R's validity - 1st edition certainly not - that describes what is commonly known as K&R C, and _is_ obsolete.  The 2nd edition is dated, describing ANSI/ISO C 90, so while I would not recommend it - especially the exercises as it happens, it is not entirely invalid - but perhaps not a book for learning C.

Comment: @Davislor : Your reasoning does not quite add up. `getchar()` must be able to return an EOF value that is not a valid character.  That is a much more convincing argument - i.e. it is by necessity rather than accident.

Comment: "Is all above correct?".  Note: `main()` without a return type is obsolete.  Recommend `int main(void)`

Comment: @Clifford That’s true of `getchar()` today, but it would be the same way even without that. In K&R C, virtually all `char` values were promoted to `int` before being used.  Therefore, the type of a character literal is `int` and the standard library uses `int` when passing or returning `char` values, even in contexts such as `strchr()` where they never represent `EOF`. Functions such as `printf()` also promote their variadic arguments, after the format string, according to the old rules, so a `%c` specifier still takes an `int` argument.

Comment: In other words: `getchar()` would have returned `int` anyway, because that’s how K&R C worked, and the library then took advantage of that to implement `EOF`. I don’t mind explaining it to beginners that way, but then they ask about all the other cases, like `'a'` being an `int` and not a `char`, that have no such logical explanation.

Comment: Thank you all. It's greatly appreciated. Regarding the book, @Clifford - I understand that K&R book is somewhat outdated but which one you will suggest as a good one?

Comment: @Davislor : You should not perhaps conflate K&R C with the book _by_ K&R - the second edition of The C Programming Language described ANSI/ISO C 90, and that is I imagine what the question is referring to.

Comment: The legacy integer promotion rules have been with us continuously to the present. In particular, ANSI C couldn’t break compatibility with pre-ANSI C libraries, so all the functions that took or returned `int` instead of `char` still had to use `int` in 1990. And you see that in plenty of places in the standard library where the possibility of `EOF` would be actively detrimental.

Comment: @Plar625 : Few have written a better book on C IMO.  Most authors started writing C++ books from the mid 1990's and there was no compelling market for new C books.  Also C is a small language well served by free on-line resources, further discouraging authors and publishers alike from investing in new material on the subject.

Comment: @Clifford - Good one. Thanks! My plan is to stick with C for a while until I feel comfortable (like a year or two) and move on C++. I will finish the K&R book 2nd edition (I believe even if it's a bit outdated it won't hurt to finish it? :-) ) and move to another one like: "C Programming: A Modern Approach, 2nd Edition" by K.N.King after that I plan to read some Algorithms and Data Structures and then start C++. :-)

Comment: I've updated my original question above. Please check it out and let me know if it's correct. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 5):

The crucial piece of information you are missing is this sentence, from the [specification of `fgetc`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.7.1) (`getchar` is defined to be equivalent to `fgetc(stdin)`):

> If the end-of-file indicator for the input stream pointed to by stream is not set and a next character is present, the fgetc function [returns] that character *as an `unsigned char` converted to an `int`*.  [Otherwise, it returns `EOF`.]

Emphasis mine.  What this means is, on the typical implementation where `unsigned char` can represent the values 0 through 255 inclusive, `getchar` will always return values in the range 0 through 255 inclusive, or EOF, *even if `char` is signed*.

EOF, meanwhile, is not guaranteed to be −1 (although it almost always is), but it *is* guaranteed to be negative, and to fit in an `int`.

So, when you do

```
int c = getchar();
```

you can be certain that none of the possible return values collide with each other: `c` will either be `EOF`, which is negative, or it will be one of the values representable by `unsigned char` (0 through 255), which are all nonnegative.  If you convert `c` back to a `char` *after* you have checked that it is not EOF, that's safe; the conversion from `unsigned char` to `char` is at worst implementation-defined.

On the other hand, when you do any of these

```
char c = getchar();          // this is wrong
unsigned char d = getchar(); // also wrong
signed char e = getchar();   // also wrong
```

you lose the ability to distinguish EOF from *some* byte value that could have been in the file. The signedness of the variable is irrelevant, and so is the actual value of EOF; what matters is that `char`, `unsigned char`, and `signed char` can only represent 2<sup>CHAR_BIT</sup> different values, all of those could have been in the file, and EOF is one more.  It's the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

You should be aware that K&R is very old and no longer considered the best book to learn C from.  (I don't know what the current best book is.)

Comment: Thank you a lot, @zwol. Greatly appreciate all the explanations. Now I believe I am aware of how it works. Thanks for the K&R tip pointing that it's old book. However, I plan to stick with it until I finish it. I believe I will get a good understanding of the language and then move on Algorithms and Data Structure or possibly read another C book, modern one. At least It won't hurt to finish this K&R book. I will get some knowledge. **Also, please check my updated original question above. Just to verify it's correct.** Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

> 1.1 So, if we declare `c` as `char` and it's by default `signed char` on the system then it will still work but it will mess up if we enter a character equal to ASCII 128 and above?

If `char` is signed, the bit pattern for characters above 128 would be interpreted as negative signed values. The only true mess-up is going to happen when character `255` (`nbsp` in extended ASCII) is entered, because it would be interpreted as `EOF` on systems where it is represented by -1.

> 1.2 In the opposite, if we declare `c` as `char` and by default is `unsigned char` on the system then `getchar()` will always be NOT equal to `EOF` no matter what because we cannot store a negative value, right?

That's correct, it would never be equal to `EOF`. Any bit pattern inside `unsigned char` would end up in the range from 0..255, inclusive, when promoted to `int` for comparison with `EOF`. Hence, the comparison would be false even when `getchar()` actually returns `EOF`.

> We type some characters as input `c = getchar()` grabs this input and convert it to ASCII number after that it checks to make sure it's not equal to `EOF`.

There is no ASCII conversion going on; the character starts as an ASCII character (assuming that the system uses ASCII) or a character in whatever encoding style that your system is using.

> 3. If it is NOT equal to `EOF`, it displays the input characters as output.
> 4. It goes back in a state where we must input new characters to continue the loop.

Correct on both 3 and 4.

Comment: Re 1.2, if `char` is unsigned, then after `char c = getchar()`, c cannot ever _compare equal to_ EOF, even if `getchar` returned EOF, but the distinction between EOF and some byte value that could have been in the file is still lost. I think you should emphasize this; as is, it kinda sounds like `unsigned char c = getchar()` is OK, which it very much isn't.

Comment: @zwol Thank you for a very good comment. I edited to emphasize this point in 1.2.

Comment: @chux Right, thank you very much! I didn't realize this, but the standard actually says that "`EOF` expands to an integer constant expression, with type `int` and a negative value".

Comment: Minor pedantic note on “ASCII conversion.”  There’s still one compiler being used in the real world that assumes an encoding that isn’t ASCII-compatible: for backward-compatibility with legacy mainframe code, IBM’s z/series compiler expects IBM code page 1047, a form of EBCDIC, unless you tell it otherwise.

Comment: @Davislor I was trying to make that same point without naming EBCDIC explicitly, calling it "whatever encoding style that your system is using."

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. I believe I am one step ahead now. :-) I've updated my original question above, so please check it out to make sure I am on the right path. Thanks again!

Comment: @Plar625 Bit representation that you mentioned in the update to your question is overwhelmingly common, but it is not the only one possible. When a number that represents a negative in a shorter type is converted to a longer type (say, a `char` to an `int`) the standard requires the conversion to preserve the sign. This process is called *sign extension*. You can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - Could you post an example, please? If we declare `c` as `char` and then when it's promoted to `int` for comparison, the `EOF` value `-1` will be `1111 1111 ..... 32 times` because the sign is preserved. I think that's correct. But because `c` is already declared as `char` then it cannot store a value greater than these 8 bits of `1111 1111`, so it's still the same case. Or maybe I am missing something.

Comment: @Plar625 The data after promotion of `c` to 32 bits is not stored back to `c`. CPU reads `c`, extends it to 32 bits, uses the extended value for comparison, and then discards it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - So, how `c` declared as `char` will promote the value of `-1` to `int` to compare with `EOF -1`, so that the CPU will read it correctly? I believe it's only possible if `char` is signed by default to allow negative values but if character `#255` is executed then it will get confused because it will read the 8 bits and in fact it will be the same as value of `-1`, which means `1111 1111`, isn't that correct? And regarding the sign extension you mentioned, `c` as `char` and by default signed when promoted to `int` with value `-1` will be equal to `EOF -1`. No error, right?

Comment: @Plar625 If a `char` in the middle of the file has value of `255`, reading it into a `signed char` and then converting it to `int` for comparison with `EOF` would stop the loop, which is an error.

Comment: Yeah, actually I didn't explained what I meant correctly. It will stop the loop, which will mean that `c` is *equal* to `EOF` as #255 will be assumed that it's `-1` value of `EOF`. Is there any other case where `c` will be consfused with `-1` of `EOF`? Overall I think I got the idea of this stuff. :-)

Comment: @Plar625 255 is the only value of `c` that would be confused for `EOF`,

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - Now I think I fully understood it. So, the sign extension you mentioned above is going to do the job to make sure that `c` declared as `char` and by default signed is working correctly. We can store negative values. When promoted to `int` it will preserve the negative sign, like filling the rest of the 32 bits with `1111`. However, with the #255 is different because the system will get confused with the bit pattern of #255. It will mean -1 on the `signed char`. I think this is what you meant by saying: "Bit representation .., but it is not the only one possible.". Right?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - Thank you! And last, why `0 through 7 (# 255)`? Because `0 to 7th` digit is binary representing the actual number and the `8th` digit is for the sign either negative as `1` or positive as `0` in the two's complement for negative values, correct?

Comment: @Plar625 Yes, bit number 8 is the sign bit. Unsigned numbers 128-255 correspond to negative numbers in 8-bit representation.

Answer (score 0):

On every normal system, char is 8 bits. So it takes the values 0-255. Functions like fgetc() need to be able to return 0-255, plus -1 for EOF. So they return an int instead of a char, and we tend to pass single characters about as int rather than as char to handle EOF smoothly.