# EOF block while loop in c

Tags: c, eof

I'm trying to make a code in c, that simply write disk c information in txt file with cmd comand "Wmic logicaldisk get" but i need only numbers instead (size 4294931).
So i pick this output and put it into a txt file to get only number in input.(I know it's quite strange).

This is the full code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    system("wmic logicaldisk get size> test.txt");

    unsigned char symb;
    FILE *FileIn;
    FileIn = fopen("test.txt","rt"); 
    int getc(FILE *stream);
    while (( symb = getc(FileIn)) !=EOF) 
    {
        if( isdigit(symb))
        {
            printf("%C", symb);
        }
    }
    printf("test"); //for debug
}
```

the code work but can't exit the loop while, the number it's printed correctly but the next comands aren't executed(so the pritnf test isn't executed).

Comment: First of all, don't redeclare standard functions (like you do with `getc`). Secondly, remember that [`getc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) returns an *`int`*! This is very important for that `EOF` check!

Comment: Where do I start. 1. Check the return value from `fopen` - It may not be open. 2. Why ` int getc(FILE *stream);` ?  3. `unsigned char symb;` should be an `int`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using int for character types when comparing with EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464030/using-int-for-character-types-when-comparing-with-eof)

Comment: The funny thing is that you added an unnecessary `unsigned` to your `char`. It is unnecessary because plain `char` should be enough for simple text processing, and it's funny because chances are good your `char` is *signed* by default, which would effectively hide the error. Right until it bites you back because you did not have this as a Valuable Learning Experience.

Comment: @usr2564301 `unsigned char`  is not completely  unnecessary.  It does create problems, yet plain `char sym` bites with UB when `sym < 0` in `if( isdigit(symb))` where as `unsigned char symb;` does not.  IAC, code should use `int sym`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three things going on in your code that's wrong.

1. You redeclare a prototype for `getc`. You should not do that, since your declaration might not be the same as the official standard declaration.
2. The `getc` function returns an `int`. That is because `EOF` is an `int` constant, with the value `-1`. And `((unsigned char) -1) != -1`. This is because the `unsigned char` value `-1` is really `255` and that is not anywhere equal to `-1`. The variables you use together with `getc` (or any similar function) *must* be an `int`.
3. The `printf` format specifier `"%C"` (with an upper-case `C`) is not a standard format specifier. It is an Microsoft Visual C++ extension and is for *wide characters* of type `wchar_t`. Since your variable `symb` is not the correct type matching the format specifier you will have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). For a narrow character like yours you should use *lower* case `c`.

Comment: The explanation for `((unsigned char)-1) != -1` is incorrect: `-1` does not have a *value* of `0xffffffff`. The left operand has value `255`, is promoted to `int` with the same value and compared to value `-1` which is different.

Comment: @chqrlie Bitwise, the 32-bit `int` value `-1` is all ones, i.e. `0xffffffff` (on a two's complement system which is the vast majority of systems). But I see your point.

Comment: Yes, but the explanation is misleading. The value is not the same as the representation. You do not need the representation to explain the behavior. The code would fail with other representations as well. There is no `unsigned char` value of `-1`, when the `int` return value of `getc()` is stored into `symb`, it is converted to `unsigned char`. If `EOF` is returned and is defined as `-1` and `unsigned char` has 8 bits, `symb` gets the value `255`.