# Why the return type of getchar() is int?

Tags: c, char, int, return-type, getchar

I searched for the answer on Internet but I could not understand what is this 'EOF'?
Please let me know from basic about what is getchar() and what are it's uses?
Note that I am just a beginner of C language.

Comment: [man 3 fgetc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) - yes the type is `int` (specifically `unsigned char` cast to `int`) and you must assign to an `int` to compare against `EOF`, because `11111111` is not equal to `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111` if comparison is done with `char`.

Comment: Somewhere else the same question is already asked, it may help https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-return-type-of-getchar-in-C

Comment: It's also already answered here at least 50 times, but finding the dup takes time... [Using int for character types when comparing with EOF - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464030/using-int-for-character-types-when-comparing-with-eof)

Comment: other duplicates: [Why must the variable used to hold getchar's return value be declared as int?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18013167/995714), [int c = getchar()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7119470/995714), [Difference between int and char in getchar/fgetc and putchar/fputc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35356322/995714), [Why is type int needed to handle EOF and return of getchar()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48870708/995714)

Answer (score 0):

In C there's really no difference between a `char` and an `int`. Even character literals, like e.g. `'A'`, are almost universally promoted to `int`.

***But*** the most important thing is that `EOF` is an `int` value. If `char` is unsigned (it's implementation-specific if `char` is signed or unsigned) then when the `char` value `-1` is promoted to `int` it becomes `0x000000ff`, which is very different from the `int` value `-1` which is `0xffffffff` (assuming normal two's complement systems).